# Swift - Search for pattern of numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, numbers, pattern-matching

I am putting together an algorithm in Swift and one part of it needs to check the given array and determine if any sequence of 2 (or 3, 4 - commented out) numbers are repeating. My source was code block from Java and to my best understanding I tried to convert it to Swift - Playgrounds. It sort of works, but it throws an error after running the code

"Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound"

Before it crashes, the output is correct and delivers the sequence of the pattern. How can be this prevented please?

```
let array1 = [12, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2]
let array2 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
let array3 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
let array4 = [1, 2, 4, 12, 13, 1, 8, 4, 12, 4 ]
let array5 = [17,39,78,324,43,33,234,99,34,555,39,78,324,43,45,92 ]

func hasPattern(c:Array<Int>) {
for i in 0..<c.count {
    var jj = i + 1

    let step2 = (c.count - i) 
    for j in jj..<step2 {

        if(c[j] == c[i]){

            // pattern of 4 numbers repeating
            /*if(c[j+1] == c[i+1] && c[j+2] == c[i+2] && c[j+3] == c[i+3]){
                print("\(c[i]), \(c[i+1]), \(c[i+2]), \(c[i+3])")                    
            }*/

            // pattern of 3 numbers repeating
            /*
            if(c[j+1] == c[i+1] && c[j+2] == c[i+2]){
             print("\(c[i]), \(c[i+1]), \(c[i+2])")
             }
             */

            // pattern of 2 numbers repeating
            if(c[j+1] == c[i+1]){
                print("\(c[i]), \(c[i+1])")
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
/*
print(hasPattern(c: array1))
print(hasPattern(c: array2))
print(hasPattern(c: array3))*/
//print(hasPattern(c: array4))

print(hasPattern(c: array5))
```

What have I missed here? Thank you.

Comment: Your question is every unclear. What do you expect as output? Your `hasPattern` function is not returning anything. What are the expected outcome for your 5 sample arrays?

Comment: You're right, I should have explained it better. I was writing this block in Swift-Playgrounds, so I was able to see the output on the line with print(). On this line I would add an array and append the result numbers. This array would be then returned. So the goal is to scan an array for pattern of repeating numbers, add the pattern to an array and return it. So for the array4 it would return numbers in array [4, 12]

Comment: So in other words, you are checking that each array contains a subarray (of up to length 4) which occurs more than once? Do you want just the longest subarray that meets the condition or ALL subarrays that meet that condition?

Comment: Yes, correct and all subarrays will be needed. So for the array5 it will return 2x patterns of 2 numbers 39, 78 and 78, 324. If I choose pattern of 3 numbers, it will return just one pattern 39, 78, 324

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still feel your question not entirely clear. Does the array `[2,3,2,3,2]` has 2 repeating subsequences of `[2,3,2]` even though they share an element in common?

If you want to avoid the "Can't form Range..." error, use `stride`:

```
// A more convenient way to check if two arrays are equal
func ==(lhs: [Int], rhs: [Int]) -> Bool {
    guard lhs.count == rhs.count else { return false }

    for (l, r) in zip(lhs, rhs) {
        if l != r { return false }
    }
    return true
}

// If there's no matching pattern, this function will return nil
// instead of an aempty array. Change it if you want to
func hasPattern(array: [Int], length: Int) -> [[Int]]? {
    guard array.count >= length * 2 else { return nil }

    var result = [[Int]]()
    for i in 0..<(array.count - length) {
        let subarray1 = array[i..<(i+length)]

        for j in stride(from: i+1, to: array.count - length, by: 1) {
            let subarray2 = array[j..<(j+length)]
            if subarray1 == subarray2 {
                result.append(Array(subarray1))
            }
        }
    }
    return result.isEmpty ? nil : result
}

if let patterns = hasPattern(array: array5, length: 3) {
    print(patterns) // [[39, 78, 324], [78, 324, 43]]
} else {
    print("No repeating pattern found")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. An excellent and fast solution. Exactly what I was trying to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in your inner loop. For an array of lets say, size 5, the loops are as following:

```
for i in 0..<5
    for j in i+1..<5-i
```

There will come a point where that `+i` and `-i` collide and your lower bound becomes greater than your upper bound.

If you don't explicitly need to roll your own algoritm, it is better to perform the search using :

```
func hasPattern(elements :Array<Int>) -> Bool {
    var index = 0
    while index < (array.count - elements.count) {
        let subarray = array[index ..< (index + elements.count)]
        if subarray.elementsEqual(elements) {
            return true
        }
        index += 1
    }
    return false
}
```

Where `array` is the array you are searching in.

Comment: Thank you. But this block is missing something I think. First, I am passing an array to search in and in your function, you specify it as "elements". Did you mean "array" instead? If so, where does the elements array come from and how it is updated? There is missing a line I think, where you append the numbers with pattern to the elements array, so the count updates also.

Comment: When I change elements to array in the bracket, it always returns true, even if it should be false. Another thing is, that I actually need the pattern numbers to work with them further. I don't need the to stick to my version, yours is promising cleaner approach, but how do I make it work properly?

Comment: It's named `elements` for a reason. In common language it makes more sense to name the function `hasPattern: of elements` rather than `hasPattern: of array`. You're not looking for a pattern of arrays, you're looking for a pattern of elements. This is a design choice but does not affect functionality as an `Array` object is still passed as parameter.

Why would anything be appended? The elements array is a parameter. Call the function when you want to determine if an array contains a pattern of elements. The function returns a bool as your question was "check given array and determine..."

Comment: Sorry to appear stupid, but in that case, what is the "array"? Where does it come from and how it is incrementing its count? You posted that "array" is the array I am searching, but it should be "elements" That's what confuses me